# Running a .bat file from C# doesn't work as opening the .bat file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am trying to get the output of a process. I've achieved this by using a .bat, which contains the following text:

```
program.exe > output.txt < input.txt
```

where program.exe is my executable, output.txt is the file I want to output the data to and input.txt is just an empty file since the program wants key inputs from time to time. The .bat file works perfectly when I run it myself, but when I attempt to run it using C# code, it just doesn't finish properly.
I am trying to run it using the following code:

```
Process.Start(path);
```

I've tried a lot of different stuff but this is the code that I last tried but none of my attempts worked. Also, the .bat file doesn't run properly when you run it as an administrator and the C# program  I am using is requiring administrator permissions. Could this be the issue and not the actual process running?

Comment: I'm almost sure that you need to run `cmd.exe` and pass the `.bat` file in as a parameter. Batch files are just command line sequences, and need the command line to run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the process `cmd.exe /c [path]` (aka the process is "cmd.exe", and your arguments are `$"/c {path}"`.

When you're on the command prompt you get "program execution" and ".bat/.cmd interactive scripting".  Since you want to execute a batch file you need to tell CreateProcess that cmd.exe is what's actually running it.

Answer (score 1):

In `ProcessStartInfo` you should set `UseShellExecute` to `false`, then set `WorkingDirectory` in the path where you found that the bat is working correctly.
Below is an example to make you understand better:

```
using (Process MyProcess = new Process())
{
    var MyProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WorkingDirectory = "path",
        FileName = "file.exe",
        Arguments = "args"
    };
    MyProcess.StartInfo = MyProcessInfo;
    MyProcess.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just what I thought. The .bat file doesn't work properly when launched from an elevated app. To fix it I used this:

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
```

Worked perfectly. Fixed it really quickly but thought I'd leave this here if anybody finds himself stuck with the same thing.